# Expecting SWR library to return cached data but not happening

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

I'm using the Vercel SWR hook usrSWR and I'm expecting that I can get the data stored in cache in some faraway component rather than having to use context or some other global state manager.

Specifically, I am setting the cache data in `IndexPage` with initialData, I can see that the `data` returned is correct, but when I try and retrieve the same data from `OtherComponent` data is returned as undefined.

I have the code in codesandbox here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/useswr-global-cache-example-forked-8qxh7?file=/pages/index.js

```
import useSWR from "swr";

export default function IndexPage({ speakersData }) {
  const { data } = useSWR("globalState", { initialData: speakersData });

  return (
    <div>
      This is the Index Page <br />
      data: {JSON.stringify(data)}
      <br />
      <OtherComponent></OtherComponent>
    </div>
  );
}

function OtherComponent() {
  const { data } = useSWR("globalState");
  return <div>I'm thinking this should get my global cache but it does not {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const speakersData = [{ id: 101 }, { id: 102 }];
  return { props: { speakersData: speakersData } };
}
```

Comment: If you wait several seconds, your data actually does show up (that "few seconds" seems to be a variable amount, I had it working after 10 seconds at one point, and a full minute at another, which... isn't helpful). In `OtherComponent`, it might be worth setting a `refreshInterval` or `revalidateOnMount`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll need to pass the data down to the child component (or using React Context) to populate its `initialData` as well, otherwise it won't have any data initially - data passed to `initialData` isn't stored in cache.

Also, unless you [provide the `fetcher` method globally](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/global-configuration), you should pass it to the `useSWR` calls.

```js
import useSWR from "swr";

const getData = async () => {
  return [{ id: 101 }, { id: 102 }];
};

export default function IndexPage({ speakersData }) {
    const { data } = useSWR("globalState", getData, { initialData: speakersData });

    return (
        <div>
            This is the Index Page <br />
            data: {JSON.stringify(data)}
            <br />
            <OtherComponent speakersData={speakersData}></OtherComponent>
        </div>
    );
}

function OtherComponent({ speakersData }) {
    const { data } = useSWR("globalState", getData, { initialData: speakersData });
    return <div>I'm thinking this should get my global cache but it does not {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const speakersData = await getData();
    return { props: { speakersData } };
}
```

Comment: I get that, as that's what the example in their repo does, but I'm not understanding why the data is not available as cache? I thought the point of useSWR is so that the data is availabe in cache (like the graphql useQuery hook does).

Comment: Data passed to `initialData` will not be stored in cache. You'll have to explicitly do so with your own logic. Here's a [potential example](https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/523#issuecomment-767124385) that extends the original `useSWR` hook.